# Visibility of Entity relationship diagram usin UML Class notations

Tags: uml

When desiging a UML class diagram for sport events and team players, 
1) Should the attributes in sport class has to be public as the events gets inherited from sports and team players will take part in the sport?

Or

2) the attributes has to be private as no subclass can access the ID/Name of the sport class?

The concept is a bit confusing. The approach for visibility has to be considered in which way?

Comment: ERD is not UML. So what is your focus?

Answer (score 0):

In a general way it is preferable that the attributes are private, if needed with associated get/set operation. Note between public and private there is the visibility protected allowing a direct (and potentially dangerous) access by the inherited classes, but not the other classes.

In case of a pure data class (*entity*, e.g. a *struct* in C/C++) you can however use public attributes because there is no associated behavior / consistency to respect between the attributes, it is just group of values.

---

Are you saying the classes *sport event* and *team players* inherit the class sport ? if yes this is very strange, *sport event* and *team players* are not sports

Comment: I mean the sport has many events and event has many players perticipating in it.

Comment: Can there be an association between event and team like: class Team registers for an class event?